# putting code in the main method

Tags: java

I have been coding a java project in netbeans and I finally have everything working. Thanks in part to the support of this forum. However, I have been coding depending on what i needed my button or textarea to do. I have nothing under main method, just under the objects that are performing actions. I have found out this is not the standard. So, I need guidance on how this should work under the main method.

Comment: What do you mean, "nothing under main method"?  Presumably your program is actually running, in which case you must have *something* there...

Comment: If you are talking about java swing using netbeans netbeans generates the code that is standard i would say.

Answer (score 3):

Button and textarea? Sounds like you've written a swing app. Swing apps tend to be event driven, ie the app does things depending on what buttons get pressed, which again sounds like what you've written.

Swing apps tend to get launched by the main method like this;

```
/**
 * Main method
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}

private static void createAndShowGUI()
{
    //create your top level container and its components and set it visible
}
```

That's pretty much what your main method should look like.

Comment: Your assumptions are correct. It is a swing application and it is event driven depending on what button I press. My main method is as shown:                                                                                                                                            public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new SummaryAgentunbuf().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

Answer (score 0):

Event driven applications don't tend to do much in their main() method.  This is by design as the *main* thing the program is doing is waiting for user interaction or other events.

Indeed, if you want to reuse your code objects you should keep all the logic not directly concerned with starting from the command line in other methods.